# Is it correct to say " I will not turn myself down"?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

A man is looking for a job and finds out he does not really fulfill the requirements, nevertheless he says "I will not turn myself down, I will let them be the ones rejecting me". You can turn someone down but can you turn yourself down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a figure of speech, and it means that he will not be the person to make the decision that he will not be hired for the job.